# Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra for alg. closed $k$. Prove ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{A})$ is a closed subgroup of $GL(\mathfrak{A})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphism-group, zariski-topology

This is **Exercise 7.6.3** of Humphreys', *"Linear Algebraic Groups"*.

### The Question:

> Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra for algebraically closed field $k$. Prove that ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{A})$ is a closed subgroup of $GL(\mathfrak{A})$ (as a linear algebraic group).

*Here "closed" is with respect to the Zariski topology.*

### The Details:

For the definition of a linear algebraic group I'm using, see this:

[Showing the linear algebraic subgroup $\Bbb U_n$ of $\Bbb{GL}_n(k)$ is closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4637855/104041)

### Context:

My thoughts are that this ought to fall out nicely from the definitions. After all, the exercise is early on in the theory of linear algebraic groups.

I reckon I should be able to do this myself if I were going at a leisurely pace. However, I am keen to understand things thoroughly, so I'm going back over key concepts; there's only so much time I can allocate to it.

---

The goal is to show that ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{A})=\mathcal{V}(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of a polynomial algebra (that, to be honest, I can't identify right now - mental block - but it's something simple). This can be done indirectly.

---

I've searched in all of the "Linear Algebraic Groups" books, on Google, on MSE (via Approach0), and so on. I found a paper that mentions this theorem, but that's not surprising, given the elementary nature of it.

---

The type of answer I'm looking for is a basic approach to/outline of a proof, please. I think I would benefit from filling in the details myself.

Please help :)

Comment: A finite-dimensional algebra is completely defined by structural constants, and any automorphism of such an algebra must preserve structural constants. In my opinion, it does not need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but at least this is a very elementary one.

Choose a $k$-basis $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of $\mathfrak{A}$ as a $k$-vector space. Then for each $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have
$$
a_i a_j = \sum_{\ell=1}^n c_{ij}^\ell a_\ell
$$
for some scalars $c_{ij}^\ell\in k$. These scalars are called the *structure constants of $\mathfrak{A}$* and determine completely its structure as a $k$-algebra.

Now recall that an element $\sigma\in\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{A})$ is completely determined by a non-singular $n\times n$ matrix $(A_{ij})$, where
$$
\sigma(a_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}a_j.
$$
Define $X_{ij}(\sigma) = A_{ij}$. Then $X_{ij}$ is a regular function on $\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{A})$, and these are the coordinate functions of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{A})$ as an algebraic variety over $k$. Then it is easy to see that $R=k[X_{ij}|i,j=1,\dots,n][\det^{-1}]$ is the ring of (global) regular functions on $\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{A})$, where
$$
\det = \det(X_{ij}).
$$
(I think you already know all of this.)

In order for $\sigma$ to belong to $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{A})$, a necessary and sufficient condition is that that $\sigma(a_ia_j)=\sigma(a_i)\sigma(a_j)$ for all $i,j=1,\dots,n$. This is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^n c_{ij}^\ell \sigma(a_\ell) = \sigma(a_i)\sigma(a_j),
$$
which in turn is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^n c_{i,j}^\ell \sum_{p=1}^n A_{\ell p}a_p = \left(\sum_{\ell=1}^n A_{i\ell}a_\ell\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^n A_{jm}a_m\right) = \sum_{\ell=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^n A_{i\ell}A_{jm}\sum_{p=1}^n c_{\ell m}^p a_p.
$$
From this, you can easily see that $I$ must be the ideal in $R$ generated by the polynomials
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^n c_{ij}^\ell X_{\ell p} - \sum_{\ell=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^n c_{\ell m}^p X_{i\ell} X_{jm}
$$
for $i,j,p=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Crystal clear answer. Impressive work! +1